# How to check if boolean false

Tags: boolean-operations

I am new to java.. Please help me for the below

I need to print "Authentication failed" when Boolean is false. But the below code is displaying both Success & Failed messages even authentication is successful.
*

```
switch(choice){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter the username");
                String name = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter the password");
                String password = scan.nextLine();
                Boolean result = true;
              for(Account a :accountArray )
              {
                     result = a.authentication(name, password);
                    if(result)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Authentication successful");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result=false;
                    }


                }
               if(!result)
              {
                  System.out.println("Authentication failed");
              }

              break;
```

*

```
Current Output:
Enter the username
vicky
Enter the password
vicky123
Authentication successful
Authentication failed
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem from the output you show, you have more than one `Account` in `accountArray`, and what is happening is that one of the accounts in the array matches, but the last one does not.  So as you loop over `accountArray`, it sets `result` according to that account.  One of the accounts in the array succeeds (you print "Authentication successful" once), and the last one does not match.  After the loop you print "Authetication failed", as that last check set `result` to false.

Probably what you want it to put a `break;` after printing "Authentication successful" -- once you find an account that matches, you're done and don't want to look at any of the later accounts in the vector.  But as you never say what you are actually trying to do, it is hard to say.

In addition, the `else` clause in the loop is redundant -- it runs if `result` is false, so setting it to false again is pointless.  Your code will also leave result as true if the accountArray is empty, and not print any message; that may or may not be sensible.